# $facebook->api('/me') is returning NULL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii

I am trying to use Facebook connect in Yii framework.

The problem is I want to access user's email address and
$facebook->api('/me') is returning NULL.

How to fix that problem?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 Yii::import("ext.fconnect.*");
        $app_id = "xxx";
        $app_secret = "xxxx";
        Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;

        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $app_id,
            'secret' => $app_secret,
        ));



        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if ($user) {

            try {                 
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $user_profile = $e;
                $user = NULL;
            }

        }

        if ($user) {

            $d["logoutUrl"] = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
                'fblogout' => 'true',           
                'next' => $this->createAbsoluteUrl("main/signout")
            ));



            $d["user_info"] = $facebook->api('/' . $user);

        } else {

            $d["loginUrl"] = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email, read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos',
                'redirect_uri' => $this->request->hostInfo . $this->request->url,
            ));
        }
        $d["user"] = $user;
        $d["userprofile"] = $user_profile;
```

Comment: Seems like `$facebook->getUser()` has a problem because of the latest SDK changes. It always returns 0.

Comment: The great ext exists https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth. I used to authenticate users in a single project.

Comment: I removed the $facebook->api("/me"); from try catch block and everything started working fine for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
$d["user_info"] = $facebook->api('/' . $user);
```

Looks wrong to me. I don’t know what data type `$user` would be; I’d just use `$facebook->api('/me');` and that will give you the profile of the currently logged in and authenticated user.